# Dynamically delete points in plotly graph

Tags: python, graph, plotly

How can I delete points from a plotly generated HTML graph and have the fit line adjust dynamically?  I don't want to change the data in the code.  I would also like to update the equation of the line.  Here is the code:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly

# Scientific libraries
from numpy import arange,array,ones
from scipy import stats


# (Almost) linear sequence
y = [19, 20, 20.5, 21.5, 22, 23, 23, 25.5, 24]

# Generated linear fit
slope, intercept, r_value, p_value, std_err = stats.linregress(xi,y)
line = slope*xi+intercept

# Creating the dataset, and generating the plot
trace1 = go.Scatter(
                  x=xi,
                  y=y,
                  mode='markers',
                  marker=go.Marker(color='rgb(255, 127, 14)'),
                  name='Data'
                  )

trace2 = go.Scatter(
                  x=xi,
                  y=line,
                  mode='lines',
                  marker=go.Marker(color='rgb(255, 127, 14)'),
                  name='y = %fx + %f' % (slope, intercept)
                  )

layout = go.Layout(
                title='Linear Fit in Python',
                )

data = [trace1, trace2]
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='Linear-Fit-in-python')
```